# Java mail modify HTML message body

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I have found this question being asked here [How to modify existing Java mail MimeMessage body parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674775/how-to-modify-existing-java-mail-mimemessage-body-parts) but there is no solution presented.

I have an html email message where I need to remove the first line and froward it.
How is this achieved in Java?

Comment: how is the email encapsulated? in a java String or some other object?

Comment: well, I am using javax.mail to read messages, so I would say MimeMultipart and getting the body with mimeMultipart.getBodyPart

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you can remove the first line from text part using a simple syntax as

```
mail = mail.substring(mail.indexOf('\n')+1);
```

For removing the first line from html part use something like jsoup. [Parse html with jsoup and remove the tag block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795796/parse-html-with-jsoup-and-remove-the-tag-block)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answer to your question is just Java String manipulation, but did you see [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#forward)?